# Returning all fields in an collection MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a MongoDB that holds a collection of users. I am searching for a specific user and want to return the userKey and userDiscordId that is inside of that userDiscordId. But I can only get it to return the name of the user. This is all done using python and MongoDB.

//my query for getUser in

```
(mycol.find({}, {"_id": 0, "userDiscordId": "HugoS#6454"})):
```

//Example of user document...

```
{
  _id: 5e5532541c9d4400006bbc01
  userDiscordId: "HugoS#6454"
  userKey: "awdawdawd"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the keys that you need to be returned from database in **projection** parameter of **db.collection.find(query, projection)**. **query** parameter here expects the condition for which db will return the documents. **projection** is used to get the selected keys from the db document. So in your case, I think the query should be:

```
mycol.find({"_id": 0, "userDiscordId": "HugoS#6454"}, {"userDiscordId": 1, "userKey": 1})
```

You can find more details on this query [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Comment: Thanks alot! Can i save the value of "userKey" to a variable somehow? This is the return that i get from that query...
{'userDiscordId': 'HugoS#6454', 'userKey': 'awdawdawd'}

Comment: Do you mean adding another key with the same value as "userKey" to the object returned from the DB?

Comment: For instance if I get the return that i wrote before, then i want to save "awdawdawd" which is the value of userKey to a variable. So that i can later print it or save to a text file.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't clearly understand your concern. Once you have the returned object from the DB, you can save the "userKey" value anywhere, in the variable or in the text file.

Comment: That is what i mean haha. Sorry for the bad explaining... I want to ONLY save the value of "userKey" to a variable and nothing else. And was wondering how i would do that?

Comment: Okay. I am guessing you are using python. So suppose you are getting the returned object in "result", 

duplicateUserKey = result["userKey"]

print(duplicateUserKey)  #this will print the value of "userKey"

Comment: @HugoSigurdson Please approve the answer if it worked for you. Thanks